How to Hard Limit Of Storage Usage
Is there any way to hard limit to PV/PVC? For example;

I have two deployment in the same node.
They have separate pv/pvc. Pod 1 claims 10Gi, Pod 2 claims 15Gi
Node has 25 Gi free filesystem volume for pv's.
Storageclass provisioner is rancher and pv volumeMode is Filesystem.

As I understand, Pod 1 can write more than 10 Gi if the free storage of node is avaible. How to hard limit the pod 1 to not use more than its pvc, ie 10 Gi? I am okay with if the pod 1 tries to write more than 10 Gi, it will be evicted.
Note 1: I know that I can ResourceQuota to hard request storage but it limits pvc, not actual size.
Note 2: I know that I can hard limit empherical size using spec.containers[0].resources.limits.ephemeral-storage: 10Gi but this is ephemeral storage and it is deleted if the pod is restarted. I want to limit persistent volume
Possible Related Questions:

Pod ephemeral local storage usage exceeds the total limit of containers
PV PVC storage size settings
Limit persistent volume claim content folder size using hostPath (It may close to my question)


Not super clear to me what is the storage class provisioner. Is it is Rancher local-path-provisioner? If yes, this is not supported as you can see in https://github.com/rancher/local-path-provisioner?tab=readme-ov-file#cons

Yes, I meant the provisioner defined in storage-class. Thank you for your response

If the local paths you are exposing to containers are on a xfs filesystem, I think you might have the option to enforce the limit with xfs quota. But it's a manual procedure I think. An alternative could be to change storage provisioner with something a bit more complex. An example could be OpenEBS LVM provisioner if you have spare disks and are okay with not using host paths.

As @ AndD mentioned, if you are using the Rancher local-path-provisioner then the volume capacity limit is not supported in it.
As there is no direct way to hard limit the pod’s storage in kubernetes. You can try a workaround If you are ok to evict the pod then you can try using the sidecar container to monitor the pod and evict incase of over usage of storage. But for this you might need to script the sidecar container based on your requirement.
The other approach is you can try using the Admission controller which helps to enforce policies to limit the size of PVC usage  but it is more complicated as it requires creating a custom script to monitor and evict the pod when the usage reaches to its limit.
The other one is you might already know the use of Resource quotas of kubernetes but this approach will apply to namespace level.

It can limit the quantity of objects that can be created in a namespace by type, as well as the total amount of compute resources that may be consumed by resources in that namespace.


Thank you. Your final suggestion is not hard limit of hard disk storage. It limits the creation of PV/PVC in namespace.
I think creating sidecar container will be the best way
